# "cannot find VehicleObstacleControl module -- in module (veins::PhyLayer80211p)"

Tags: veins

I have faced the following issue in veins-5.2 simulation in the vehicle obstacle shadowing model for V2I scenario "cannot find VehicleObstacleControl module -- in module (veins::PhyLayer80211p)".  However, I can find VehicleObstacleControl module in the veins::PhyLayer80211p.cc.  I highly appreciate if you could guide me.